# Some info from a C++ vector of Cards is not printed out when printed out in a for loop?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I am working on a Black Jack simulator for a C++ class. These are the relevant classes/structures that I am working on with compilation in c++11:

**class DeckFactory**: with a static method called GetDeck() which returns a vector that holds 52 Cards. 
**class Card**: A class defined in a namespace Casino, that represents a Card and Ptr is a public member of Card that is a typedef Card *.
 
**class struct Suite**: A class defined in Card and also used to declare a member for Card as follows Suite const & _suite.
**enum SuiteType**: enum defined within the class struct Suite. it has fours members CLUBS,DIAMONDS,HEARTS,SPADES.
**class FaceCard**: A sub class of Card that has a FaceRank member declared as follows FaceRank const _rank.
**enum class FaceRank**: has the following members JACK,QUEEN,KING.
**class AceCard**: A sub class of Card.

**Problem**: When I create a deck and fill it with 52 cards in the GetDeck() method of the DeckFactory class everything works fine and it returns. However when I print out the information of each object in the vector it does not print out complete info for each object in fact it looks as if some cards were added twice which is weird as each card must be unique and I manually added unique cards to the deck in the method GetDeck(). Here is the output and below is the relevant code for each class that is involved in the printing of the vector deck.

**Output**:

[image: code output]

**main method**:

[image: main() code]

**DeckFactory GetDeck() method**:
[image: 1 part of GetDeck()]

[image: 2nd part of GetDeck()]

**ToString methods for Card, Suite, FaceCard, and AceCard respectively**:
The variable _suite is a member of Card and of type Suite. Rank() is a method that just retrieves the rank of the card 2,3,4... 10 for jacks,queens,kings, and 11 for acecards.
If any more information is needed please just ask. Thanks for the help!!!!

[image: cards tostring]
[image: suites tostring]
[image: facecards tostring]
[image: acecards tostring]

**Constructors for Card, Suite, FaceCard, AceCard**:
[image: card constructor]
[image: suite ctor]
[image: facecard ctor]
[image: acecard ctor]

Comment: Posting source code in a screenshot is not a good idea.

Comment: You're actually adding all the cards manually one by one? Consider revising to a loop (+ enums). Regarding your question - please add the card constructor.

Comment: @Leeor: I agree.  @OP: Your problem is probably in the `Card` ctor (and its derivatives'.) Also, you might want to add `default` clauses to your `switch`es to be able to catch and handle (set breakpoints, etc.) the invalid cases (for debugging purposes.)

Comment: Also, maybe not your actual problem but a HUGE red flag - you're using the same variable name for an integer and your vector iterator in your main loop. Consider changing `std::vector<Card::Ptr>::const_iterator i` to `it` instead. Bonus points, since you're using C++11, just write it as `auto it = ...`

Comment: @Commander Coriander Salamander I was iterating through with an integer before forgot to delete when I wanted to try iterators instead.

Comment: @Commander Coriander Salamander I was actually using auto to begin with but it did not make a difference so instead I used an integer i to iterate through the indices with vector at() but that did not make a difference either and now I am trying the iterator way.

Comment: @fgharo91 Posting source code in a screenshot is not a good idea, because people have no way of quoting a bad fragment and/or correcting it.

Comment: It's a really good way to ensure that most don't even read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `_suite` data member of `Card` is a `const Suite &`. If you 
change the type to `const Suite`, I suspect you will get the behavior you want.

When you construct a new `Card` like this,

`deck.push_back(new Casino::Card(2, Casino::Card::Suite::CLUBS);`

Notice that there will be a temporary `Suite` object being constructed off of your enum value, `CLUBS`. That temporary object's life-time is only within your constructor, so you must copy or move it in to your `Card` object. Otherwise, `_suite` is only referring to a memory location which can be overwritten with something else.

Comment: Well I took off the '&' off of _suite in the Card class and now all the regular cards are outputted with there rank along with there suite. However the Jack,Queen,King, and Ace are do not print out with their suite. Perhaps I need to tinker a bit with the inheritance code for those sub classes.

Comment: Yes! Thanks for your answer! I went and looked at the hpp file that had Card, FaceCard, and AceCard and there was a _suite variable in all those classes declared as Suite const &. I took off all the &s and now it is working! Thanks again. The weird thing is that code was given to us by the teacher already coded like that :p

Comment: Alternatively, if I kept the & on that variable in the classes how would I copy the values from the call variable instead of the reference? deck.push_back(new Casino::Card(2,Casino::Card::Suite::CLUBS)); How would I copy the values from Suite into my _suite variable with it being declared with &? Just for curiosity?

Comment: Note if you're publicly inheriting `AceCard` and `FaceCard` from `Card`, they should __be__ `Card`s. As in, they shouldn't have their own `_suite` members, they should use the one in `Card`. For `AceCard`, you're already calling `Card`'s constructor correctly, so you can just get rid of the `_suite` member in `AceCard`. For `FaceCard`, consider getting rid of `FaceRank` and just using other ints, and calling `Card`'s constructor like `AceCard`.

Comment: As for what if the member variable had the & on it, one way would be to have another variable store the data, and have the member variable with the & on it just refer to it, but this is clearly useless. Another way would be to store the data in the heap, and you refer to the heap allocated data with the member. This one could be used to keep the size of the object smaller, but even then, the member should be a `std::unique_ptr<>`, or `std::shared_ptr<>` instead of a bare reference.